# How to exclude missing values from MCA (multiple correspondence analysis) in R?

Tags: r

When carrying out multiple correspondence analysis using SPSS, one has three options for how to deal with missing values: one may exclude missing values, impute missing values, or exclude objects with missing values (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fidh_mcan_missing.htm). However, the R package FactoMineR (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/FactoMineR/docs/MCA) by default treats missing values as an extra level.

To make up for this problem, the missMDA package exists, which enables the user to impute missing values (http://math.agrocampus-ouest.fr/infoglueDeliverLive/developpement/missMDA). Wonderful if that's what you want to do with those values, but what if you want to exclude them instead? How can one achieve that using R? (I am open to using a different package than FactoMineR.)

Comment: I'll suggest one quick answer without know what you're talking about...  Sometimes the option na.rm=TRUE does the trick.  Can you try that?

Comment: Without knowing what your data look like, I can only suggest a limited set of ideas.  Are you looking to only include complete cases (i.e. observations with no missing values)?  If so, maybe you are looking for something like `data[complete.cases(data), ]`

Comment: @Frank what you're suggesting would be equivalent to the third option provided by SPSS - so it's useful to know (hence my up vote on your comment) but doesn't answer my question. What I'm trying to achieve is a bit different. In the analysis of each variable, I want account to be taken only of cases for which that particular value is not missing. (Since you asked about my data, it consists of under three hundred cases with under a dozen categorical variables. Just one of the variables - always the same one - is missing in a small minority of cases, but I don't want to exclude them altogether.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the soc.ca package on CRAN. It supports specific multiple correspondence analysis - where you can set missing or any other type of value as passive. They still count in the calculation of the mass, but are not included in the solution. It is an elegant way of handling missing data without losing the information you have. You can read more about it here:

Le Roux, Brigitte, and Henry Rouanet 2010 Multiple Correspondence Analysis. Thousand Oaks: Sage.